# File already in use with database MS-ACCESS in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, database-connection, connection-string, oledb

I'm trying to open the database by access and then I run the application in vb.net then an error appears

`File already in use`.

If I don't open the MS-ACCESS database then running the application has no problems. Is there a solution with code or or is there something wrong with my code? . Please guide.

Thanks

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
    Dim Path As String = "|DataDirectory|\students.accdb"
    Private WithEvents dt As New DataTable
    Dim cn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=" & Path & "; Persist Security Info=False;"
    Private Sub PopulateDataGridView()
        Try
            dt = New DataTable
            Dim query = "select * FROM [students]"
            Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(query, cn.ToString)
                adapter.Fill(dt)
            End Using
            Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        Catch myerror As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            'cn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.PopulateDataGridView()
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: file already in use]
[image: client settings default open mode exclusive]

Comment: There's some weirdness in your code that shows that you're not really think about the details. Firstly, you declare `Path` as type `String` explicitly but then you don't do the same for `cn`. Make up your mind how you're going to declare variables and do it consistently. You later call `ToString` on `cn` when it's already a `String`. That's either pointless because the type is inferred anyway or pointless because you should have declared the variable with an explicit type. You also declare `Path` where `path` would be consistent with all your other variable names.

Comment: Also, what's the point of that `Path` variable in the first place? You assign a literal to it and then you concatenate that into another literal later. Why not just use one literal containing the whole connection string? Also, `cn` is a bad name because the variable doesn't refer to an actual connection but just the connection string.

Comment: This one is less of an issue but, as you're only retrieving data with your data adapter, I would not use a data adapter at all. I might use a data reader and call the `DatraTable.Load` method. In fact, if you're only viewing and not editing the data, you don't even need a `DataTable`. You can bind a data reader to a `BindingSource` and bind that to the grid. If you are going to make changes then you should be keeping the data adapter and using it later to save those changes.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question with your latest screenshot. I missed that Access setting when I looked. It seems the obvious solution is to change that from Exclusive to Shared. That said, I just checked and it's set to Shared on my machine but I'm not sure that I can open a data file using ADO.NET anyway. I thought that I'd got the same error as you in the past. I'll test that now.

Comment: When you default the database to open Exclusive, you can only have it open for one user - that's why you can't open it, and then open it again (from your application). I'm voting to close as this is really supposed to be obvious here :)

Comment: I just tested and can confirm that setting that option to Shared enables you to open the file elsewhere. I'm sure I got the same error as you in the past so maybe I changed that setting myself at some point, but I have no recollection of doing so. Not the first time something like that has happened though.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , ` If you want to see changes made by your app, just open Access after making them`  
What do you mean by setting in the database as I screenshotted but it is already set to exclusive

Comment: When a database is opened exclusively in Access, you cannot open a connection to it somewhere else, since the file is locked. That's all. The same applies to any file

Comment: @jmcilhinney ,  `I just tested and can confirm that setting that option to Shared enables you to open the file elsewhere.` You are right. 
solution solved

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `You later call ToString on cn when it's already a String. That's either pointless because the type is inferred anyway or pointless because you should have declared the variable with an explicit type. You also declare Path where path would be consistent with all your other variable names. `  if I make  `cn.ToString` without `tostring` but an error `Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called without a narrowing conversion`  please guide me

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `This one is less of an issue but, as you're only retrieving data with your data adapter, I would not use a data adapter at all. I might use a data reader and call the DatraTable.Load method. In fact, if you're only viewing and not editing the data, you don't even need a DataTable. You can bind a data reader to a BindingSource and bind that to the grid. If you are going to make changes then you should be keeping the data adapter and using it later to save those changes` 
so I don't need to use datatable if it's just for viewing or reading, please guide me

Comment: It's OK to do what you're doing with the data adapter and `DataTable` but there are lighter options if there's no editing and saving. See the fourth code snippet [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872) for loading a data reader into a `DataTable` and see [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?887311) for binding a data reader directly.